# How to load test a JavaScript heavy web application (JIRA)?

Tags: javascript, ajax, selenium, jmeter, performance-testing

I would like to load test a web application which uses a lot of JavaScript items on each of its web pages. For example, there is a dashboard page which contains an overview section, a section displaying the results of user-specific queries and other user configurable sections. Each page access therefore generates a large number of additional requests to the web application, which change depending on the particular user and permissions, and this is really difficult to model in JMeter or similar programs.

I was considering using Selenium to run my tests (which uses a real web browser so all JavaScript objects are properly executed and rendered) however Selenium is not a load testing tool, I probably need one VM per Selenium client and each of those VMs has to run Windows or a Linux desktop.

What I am looking for is a web test software which interprets JavaScript just like a real web browser, but runs from the command line and allows me to run more than one client per session.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any load testing software capable of executing JavaScript and rendering HTML. You could try simulating these JavaScript-driven requests in JMeter test.

1. [First of all, you should be able to record them using HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
2. Second - you can use [Transaction Controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller) to measure the aggregate time of the main request and sub-requests.
3. You need to find out a way to simulate these AJAX requests in parallel, check out [How to Load Test AJAX/XHR Enabled Sites With JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-load-test-ajaxxhr-enabled-sites-jmeter) article for more details on setting up JMeter for this